# Radius of convergence for series with product

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I find the radius of convergence for this series?

[image: problem]

The answer listed says 16 but I'm not sure how to solve this, is there a specific formula to generalize the power series?

Comment: Use the ratio test.

Comment: @Kroki can you elaborate on how I can express this with the ratio test?